# Trying to implement a minimax algorithm for a tic-tac-toe game in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I'm trying to implement a minimax algorithm for a tic-tac-toe game in C++, and it's mostly going well. However, the way I've implemented the algorithm isn't right, as when I test the game against the AI it seems to make moves at random, rather than the best move possible. It won't try to prevent the player from winning, and it doesn't even win when it clearly can win.

I'm pretty sure it's the way I've implemented the minimax algorithm below:`

```
Move Move::minMaxMove(char _board[][3], char player, int &_xIndex, int &_yIndex)
{

    int game = checkWin(_board);

    //Variable to hold the best move
    Move bestMove;

    //If the game is over
    if (game != -1)
    {
        return game;
    }

    //If games in progress
    if (game == -1)
    {
        //Move(-1);

        if (player == 'X')
        {
            int max = -1000;

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if (_board[i][j] == ' ')
                    {
                        _board[i][j] = 'X';

                        //Recursion down the tree, error here maybe
                        Move move = minMaxMove(_board, 'O', _xIndex, _yIndex);
                        if (move.score > max)
                        {
                            max = move.score;
                            _xIndex = i;
                            _yIndex = j;
                        }

                        _board[i][j] = ' ';
                    }
                }
            }

            bestMove.xIndex = _xIndex;
            bestMove.yIndex = _yIndex;
            bestMove.score = max;

            return bestMove;
        }

        else
        {
            int min = 1000;

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if (_board[i][j] == ' ')
                    {
                        _board[i][j] = 'O';

                        //Recursion down the tree
                        Move move = minMaxMove(_board, 'X', _xIndex, _yIndex);
                        if (move.score < min)
                        {
                            min = move.score;
                            _xIndex = i;
                            _yIndex = j;
                        }

                        _board[i][j] = ' ';
                    }
                }
            }

            bestMove.xIndex = _xIndex;
            bestMove.yIndex = _yIndex;
            bestMove.score = min;

            return bestMove;
        }
    }
}
```

And the checkWin function is here:

```
int Move::checkWin(char _board[][3])
{

    int game = -1;

    //Checks for a three in a throw of either symbol 'X' or 'O' and awards 10 points for 'X' and -10 for 'O'
    if (_board[0][0] == 'X' && _board[0][0] == _board[0][1] && _board[0][1] == _board[0][2]) { game = 10; }
    else if (_board[1][0] == 'X' && _board[1][0] == _board[1][1] && _board[1][1] == _board[1][2]) { game = 10; }
    else if (_board[2][0] == 'X' && _board[2][0] == _board[2][1] && _board[2][1] == _board[2][2]) { game = 10; }
    else if (_board[0][0] == 'X' && _board[0][0] == _board[1][0] && _board[1][0] == _board[2][0]) { game = 10; }
    else if (_board[0][1] == 'X' && _board[0][1] == _board[1][1] && _board[1][1] == _board[2][1]) { game = 10; }
    else if (_board[0][2] == 'X' && _board[0][2] == _board[1][2] && _board[1][2] == _board[2][2]) { game = 10; }
    else if (_board[0][0] == 'X' && _board[0][0] == _board[1][1] && _board[1][1] == _board[2][2]) { game = 10; }
    else if (_board[0][3] == 'X' && _board[0][2] == _board[1][1] && _board[1][1] == _board[2][0]) { game = 10; }

    else if (_board[0][0] == 'O' && _board[0][0] == _board[0][1] && _board[0][1] == _board[0][2]) { game = -10; }
    else if (_board[1][0] == 'O' && _board[1][0] == _board[1][1] && _board[1][1] == _board[1][2]) { game = -10; }
    else if (_board[2][0] == 'O' && _board[2][0] == _board[2][1] && _board[2][1] == _board[2][2]) { game = -10; }
    else if (_board[0][0] == 'O' && _board[0][0] == _board[1][0] && _board[1][0] == _board[2][0]) { game = -10; }
    else if (_board[0][1] == 'O' && _board[0][1] == _board[1][1] && _board[1][1] == _board[2][1]) { game = -10; }
    else if (_board[0][2] == 'O' && _board[0][2] == _board[1][2] && _board[1][2] == _board[2][2]) { game = -10; }
    else if (_board[0][0] == 'O' && _board[0][0] == _board[1][1] && _board[1][1] == _board[2][2]) { game = -10; }
    else if (_board[0][3] == 'O' && _board[0][2] == _board[1][1] && _board[1][1] == _board[2][0]) { game = -10; }

    //All the spaces are filled and there is no three in a row
    else if (_board[0][0] != ' ' && _board[0][1] != ' ' && _board[0][2] != ' ' &&
        _board[1][0] != ' ' && _board[1][1] != ' ' && _board[1][2] != ' ' &&
        _board[2][0] != ' ' && _board[2][1] != ' ' && _board[2][2] != ' ')
    {
        //Game is a draw
        game = 0;
    }

    else
    {
        //Game is in progress
        game = -1;
    }

    return game;
}
```

If anyone can give me some advice or spot what I've done wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Min Maxing is choosing the best local move, while avoiding expanding the search tree, it doesn't guarantee success, only local goodness.  You might consider implementing a larger board, and seeing if your AI can beat you.

Comment: You have `if (game != -1) { return game; }`, even though `minMaxMove` is supposed to return a `Move`?